# Jquery explaination on functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi can some one explain to me  what is meant by the two following function declarations

```
$(function() {

});
```

and

```
jQuery(function($){ 

});
```

Thanks

Comment: [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com)

Comment: None of them is valid syntactically.

Comment: More specifically, http://api.jquery.com/jquery

Comment: they are not valid function

Comment: A clear disregard for Google here....

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the API docs here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3

`$(function(){})` and `jQuery(function(){})` are, for most practical purposes, the same thing. $ is a kind of an "alias" for `jQuery`. Whenever you pass a function as the first argument into `$()` or `jQuery()`, it will call that function when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be best explained by Paul Irish in the `10 Things I Learnt From JQuery Source` video he made.

He not only covers your question, but various other points - well worth a watch!!

http://www.paulirish.com/2010/10-things-i-learned-from-the-jquery-source/

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much like the `document.onload`: the script will be executed when everything has been load.
It's very useful when you do some [DOM manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).

Comment: Not specifically true - document.onload and document.onready are slightly different... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready